# oracle transposing rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

my question is about transposing rows into columns.
I have got table T1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) columns with datatype varchar2, i want to transpose the rows obtained,
example:

```
select * from T1
```

gives

```
      c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
row1  1   2   3   4   5
row2  A   B   C   D   E
....
rown  U   V   W   X   Y
```

the result expected is

```
C1 1 A......U
C2 2 B......V     
C3 3 C......W
C4 4 D......X
C5 5 E......Y
```

all rows in different columns(table contains only 10-15 rows)
i have tried the following query, but it isnt giving  expected result.

```
  Select RN,value 
    From (
           Select x.*,row_number () 
             Over ( Order By c1) rn From T1 x) 
          Unpivot (value For value_type In (C1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

So you only need to pivot data again:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98dcdc4639ead219248895292425f51c)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (
      select rn, val, col
        from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by c1) rn from t1) 
        unpivot (val for col in (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5))) 
  pivot (max(val) for rn in (1, 2, 3, 4)) 
  order by col
```

You have to know how many rows are in `t1` and list them all in pivot `in` clause `(1, 2, 3, 4)` alternatively adding aliases for each column.

Comment: @RohithManderwad kindly, you could try to mark the answer.