# Oracle- Need help in Table data representation in different format

Tags: excel, oracle, powerbi

I have a table in Oracle in similar that can be seen below.
[image]

Need to represent the data in below format:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533241/oracle-transposing-rows-to-columns

Comment: If you're using Power BI just use a Matrix Visual to transpose the data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual

Answer (score 0):

You want to transpose rows and columns; don't do that in Oracle.

SQL (in all dialects, not just Oracle's) does not support returning an arbitrary number of columns or naming those unknown columns with dynamically created identifiers. If you were to try to do this in SQL you would have to restrict the output to a fixed number of columns with fixed names.

---

If you want all the data then use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table
```

And then in the third-party language (i.e. C, Java, PHP, Python, etc.) you are using to access the database then transpose rows and columns in that (and not in SQL).

---

If you did want to transpose the values in SQL for a fixed set of known months then `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
       UNPIVOT(
         value FOR server_lifecycle IN (
           server_count_start      AS 'Server Count Start',
           new_servers_provision   AS 'New Servers Provision',
           m_and_a_server_addition AS 'M and A Server Addition',
           moved_to_cloud          AS 'Moved to Cloud',
           decomissioned           AS 'Decomissioned',
           server_count_last       AS 'Server Count Last'
         )
       )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(value) FOR month IN (
           DATE '2023-10-01' AS "Oct-23",
           DATE '2023-11-01' AS "Nov-23",
           DATE '2023-12-01' AS "Dec-23"
         )
       );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q0Syf8TN)

Comment: I don't have fixed set of known months, its a table which will store historic data. I will access excel or powerbi to showcase the data in above format. Please guide how to transpose the data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data and on how wide you want your result to be - one option is to use [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm). To use it you have to set the boundary on number of months you want to process and report. In this answer I set it to 6 months but it can be widened ...

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select  DATE '2023-10-01' "A_MONTH",  23550 "COUNT_START", 160 "NEW_PROVISION", 0 "ADDITION", 2 "MOVED", 1298 "DECOMISSIONED", 22410 "COUNT_LAST" From Dual Union All 
          Select  DATE '2023-11-01' "A_MONTH",  22410 "COUNT_START", 341 "NEW_PROVISION", 0 "ADDITION", 0 "MOVED",  454 "DECOMISSIONED", 22297 "COUNT_LAST" From Dual Union All
          Select  DATE '2023-12-01' "A_MONTH",  22297 "COUNT_START",  65 "NEW_PROVISION", 0 "ADDITION", 0 "MOVED",  297 "DECOMISSIONED", 22065 "COUNT_LAST" From Dual 
        ),
```

... create a CTE (named it grid) defining text for your first column

```sql
  grid AS
      ( Select    1 "RN", 'Lifecycle: ON-PREM' "TXT" From Dual Union All
        Select    2,      'Server Count, 1st of New Month'   From Dual Union All
        Select    3,      'New Server Provisioning' From Dual Union All
        Select    4,      'M' || '&' || 'A server addition '  From Dual Union All
        Select    5,      'Move to Cloud'  From Dual Union All
        Select    6,      'Decomm (excl. Move to Cloud)' From Dual Union All
        Select    7,      'Server Count, Last Day of Month'  From Dual
      ),
```

Modeling,
combine grid cte with your table data and iterate rules for number of months to report (here it is 6)

```sql
  months AS 
      ( Select  *
        From    ( Select  g.RN, g.TXT, 
                          To_Char(t.A_MONTH, 'Mon-yy') "A_MONTH", t.COUNT_START, t.NEW_PROVISION, t.ADDITION, t.MOVED, t.DECOMISSIONED, t.COUNT_LAST,
                          ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By g.RN Order By g.RN, t.A_MONTH) "RN_MONTH"
                  From    grid g
                  Inner Join tbl t ON(1 = 1)
                )
            MODEL   Dimension By ( RN, RN_MONTH )
                    Measures     ( TXT, A_MONTH, COUNT_START, NEW_PROVISION, ADDITION, MOVED, DECOMISSIONED, COUNT_LAST,
                                   'xxx-xx' "M1", 'xxx-xx' "M2",  'xxx-xx' "M3",  'xxx-xx' "M4",  'xxx-xx' "M5",  'xxx-xx' "M6" )
                    RULES ITERATE(6)
                          ( M1[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 1],
                            M2[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 2],
                            M3[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 3],
                            M4[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 4],
                            M5[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 5],
                            M6[1, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = A_MONTH[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 1],
                            M2[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 2],
                            M3[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 3],
                            M4[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 4],
                            M5[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 5],
                            M6[2, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_START[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 1],
                            M2[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 2],
                            M3[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 3],
                            M4[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 4],
                            M5[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 5],
                            M6[3, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = NEW_PROVISION[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 1],
                            M2[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 2],
                            M3[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 3],
                            M4[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 4],
                            M5[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 5],
                            M6[4, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADDITION[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 1],
                            M2[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 2],
                            M3[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 3],
                            M4[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 4],
                            M5[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 5],
                            M6[5, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = MOVED[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 1],
                            M2[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 2],
                            M3[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 3],
                            M4[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 4],
                            M5[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 5],
                            M6[6, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = DECOMISSIONED[CV(), 6],
                            --
                            M1[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 1],
                            M2[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 2],
                            M3[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 3],
                            M4[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 4],
                            M5[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 5],
                            M6[7, ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = COUNT_LAST[CV(), 6]
                          )
      )
```

Select and filter what you need from modeled data

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select    TXT, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6
From      months
Where     RN_MONTH = 1
Order By  RN
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
TXT                             M1     M2     M3     M4     M5     M6    
------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
Lifecycle: ON-PREM              Oct-23 Nov-23 Dec-23                     
Server Count, 1st of New Month  23550  22410  22297                      
New Server Provisioning         160    341    65                         
M&A server addition             0      0      0                          
Move to Cloud                   2      0      0                          
Decomm (excl. Move to Cloud)    1298   454    297                        
Server Count, Last Day of Month 22410  22297  22065                         */
```

MODEL clause processes data like in excel spreadsheet. It looks complicated and overcoded at first but  it is definetely worth to learn. It is reliable and very fast....